# How do you set the sort order for event observers in Magento?

Tags: events, magento, magento-1.9, observers, magento-1.4

I have created an observer on the `catalog_product_save_after` event, but it seems to be getting called before the catalogrule observer that runs the `applyAllRulesOnProduct()` method.  I need to call mine after `applyAllRulesOnProduct()` runs.  How is the order for these observers chosen?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The answer, like many in Magento, is complicated.  There's also **two** possible problems your specific situation might relate to.  This is going to be long — skip to the end for the contextless short version.

#### Module Loading Order

There is not way to **explicitly** set an observer sort order.  Magento will run through the events in the order they've been [merged into the global configuration](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#magento_config).  So, while you can't control the order of event specifically, you **can** control the order Magento loads and merges modules in by using the `<depends/>` tag in your `app/etc/modules` XML declaration file.

For example, in the `Mage_Api2.xml` file

```
<!-- File: app/etc/modules/Mage_Api2.xml -->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Api2>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>core</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Core />
                <Mage_Oauth />
            </depends>
        </Mage_Api2>
    </modules>
</config>
```

the author has indicated that the `Mage_Api2` module *depends* on the `Mage_Core` and `Mage_Oauth` modules.  This means `Mage_Api2`'s `config.xml` file will be merged **after** the `config.xml` files of `Mage_Core` and `Mage_Oauth`.  This means that events defined in `Mage_Api2` will run after events defined in `Mage_Core` and `Mage_Oauth`.

Lacking a `<depends/>` node, the rules for module loading are

1. All **core** modules are loaded before non-core modules
2. The remaining modules are loaded alphabetically.

It would be good form to have your module depend on the `Mage_CatalogRule` module (where the `applyAllRulesOnProduct` observer method is defined).  **However**, it should not be necessary, as all core modules are loaded before non-core modules.

That's because there's another factor in the order event observer methods are run in.

#### Area Order

In addition to module order, you'll also need to consider which **area** your event observer is defined in.  That is, when you create an event observer in Magento, you drop in some `config.xml` that looks like this

```
<config>
    <!-- ... -->
    <global>
        <!-- ... -->
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <abc_abc>
                        <class>abc_abc/observer</class>
                        <method>test</method>
                    </abc_abc>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>       
    </global>
</config>
```

In the above example, this event observer has been defined in the `global` area (because it's inside the `<global/>` node).  This means the observer will run in **both** the `frontend` and `adminhtml` areas of Magento.  However, it's also possible to **restrict** the area your event is run in.  For example, the `catalogrule` event you mentioned is defined in the `adminhtml` area

```
<!-- #File: app/code/core/Mage/CatalogRule/etc/config.xml -->
<config>
    <!-- ... -->
    <adminhtml>
        <!-- ... -->
        <events>
            <!-- ... -->
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <catalogrule>
                        <class>catalogrule/observer</class>
                        <method>applyAllRulesOnProduct</method>
                    </catalogrule>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

This means this event observer will only run in Magento's backend `adminhtml` area.  In other words, it only runs when you save an event in the backend admin console.

**This** is where I think your problem is, because in modern versions of Magento (and possibly the old ones), event observers from the `<global/>` node always run before event observers in the `<adminhtml/>` node.  My guess is your event is in the `<global/>` node.  Try moving it to the `<adminhtml/>` node.

**The Short Version**: Make sure your module `<depends/>` on the `Mage_CatalogRule` module, and move your event observer configuration to the `<adminhtml/>` node in your module's `config.xml`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation; it makes perfect sense now. Only tweak was to use `Mage_CatalogRule` (capital "R") for the `<depends/>`.  Works perfectly now.  Thanks, again!

Comment: Just as a reference, a third option could be: disable the observer from catalogrule ( just set the type>disabled</type in your config.xml for that node) and call the method inside your own observer: Mage::getSingleton('catalogrule/observer')->applyAllRulesOnProduct($event);, at the beginning or the end of your listener (depending what you want of course)

Comment: Not an appropriate use of the comments section, but I couldn't resist -- Nearly 10 years into Magento now and I still am discovering helpful write-ups from you @AlanStorm. Be it Magento 1 or Magento 2, thank you for your contributions to the community.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old thread, but in case anyone wants to change the load order of their module:

The /etc/modules/* folder is loaded alphabetically, so if your module's file comes first (or last) it is loaded in that order accordingly- So you could just rename /etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml to /etc/modules/ZZZNamespace_Module.xml to have it loaded last (assuming there aren't any other modules with ZZZZ...)

Also, to clarify, everything else in your module can remain intact (code/file and folder names), you would just change this one file which can be named anything you choose.